# What is the purpose of API Resources?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I've read the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-resources) and watched the Laracast. I'm still left wondering why you would use them?

I get that you can map different data to different names if your field names were to change but you want to keep a consistent public API. But surly you can just do the same on the model with the toArray() method and change the mappings there?

If I were to do:

```
return User::find(1);
```

I get a response like:

```
{"id":1,"name":"Ova Parker"}
```

If I do:

```
return new UserResource(User::find(1));
```

I get a response like:

```
{"data":{"id":1,"name":"Ova Parker"}}
```

Is there a significance in wrapping it with a data tag? I am just guessing but is this a standard JSON format for API's? Why would you not just do `return User::find(1);` instead of using an API resource, if this is under API routes then it'll return it as JSON anyway automatically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You kind of answer the question by yourself. The idea behind API Resources or Transformers (like the ones from [Fractal](http://fractal.thephpleague.com/transformers/)) is to hide the db field names from the client. With `return User::find(1)` you expose your whole db structure which might not a good idea security-wise and also bad for the release process. If you need to change a db field name, you have to change the API too. With Resources you have a mapping between your application and the consumer of you API.

It seems more work in the beginning, but once you started it, you won't wanna miss it anymore.

There is no `toArray()` method in PHP, which gets magically called like `__toString()`. You have to write you own and call it by yourself. Resources are built-in by Laravel and will be resolved automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the information - is there also a reasoning behind how a API resource will output the data in a data tag? Whereas just returning it does not. Why does it do this/is this a good idea?

Comment: This is just how Taylor built it. There is not standard behind. You can also remove it. See https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-resources#data-wrapping

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer.